# Telegram bot, session lifetime

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I know that a telegram bot can't start conversation with the user. So user should click "/start" first. But for how long bot can respond to the user after the last message? Do any limitations exist like 24/48 hours?

Answer (score 0):

> Do any limitations exist like 24/48 hours?

**No**. After a user starts a conversation with a bot, the bot can send messages to that user until one of the following actions occur:

- User 'Stop and blocks' the bot (See picture below)
- User account gets deleted

---

For example, using the Desktop version, the user can 'Stop and block' a bot by pressing the following button:

[image]